# Trying to extend Layout. File not used at all

Tags: layout, theme, extend, magento-2.1.7

I try to extend

- `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

Therefore I created

- `/app/design/frontend/Company/basic/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

inside my sub-theme with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

In the end I want to add content under the purchased items. Removing something is just for seeing if it works.

The theme is correctly used as far as I can see (I can overwrite templates inside the sub-theme folder)

But nothing changes on this page:

- domain-dev.de/sales/order/view/order_id/1/

If I change `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml` directly it works. But obviously this is not the correct way of doing things.

I also tried to add a block via `sales_order_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" name="customtext" template="customtextab.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and therefore added the file `/app/design/frontend/Company/basic/Magento_Sales/templates/customtext.phtml` 
with this content:

```
<div class="block" style="float: right;margin-bottom: 0.5%;margin-top: 0.5%;">
    <?php echo __('This is Custom Text overwritten'); ?>
</div>
```

like described here: [How To Use Magento 2 Layouts](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-layouts-blocks-templates/)

But nothing changes. I flushed the cache every time:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

And installed the theme by doing

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I'm using Magento 2.1.7 with the vagrant box from paliarush: https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers in case that matters.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it somehow myself.

I tried the exact same codebase on different infrastructures. It worked without any further investigation on aws/ec2 and vagrant/virtualbox.

Both are created with my own boot scripts. Could be that some configuration of the paliarush magento2 box prevented the layout cache to be flushed.